# Paste from clipboard not working with React Native on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

As the title says, I'm working on an app that has an input text and when I tried pasting text I had on the clipboard, it wouldn't do anything, but it shows the new notification saying that "the text from clipboard was assessed".

After that, I installed `@react-native-community/clipboard` and tried manually sending something to the clipboard:

```js
Clipboard.setString('https://google.com');
const text = await Clipboard.getString();
console.log('clipboard', { text });
```

And it was always empty... but: If I switched to a different app, it would paste the URL I sent; and if I run the app on a device, it would work.

Now, a some info on the environment:

- Mac mini M1
- Xcode 12.5
- Simulator for iPhone 12 with iOS 14.5
- Node 14.16
- React Native 0.64.1

Stuff I already tried:

- Restarting the device.
- Resetting the device settings.
- Playing with the check for the pasteboard sync.
- Using the software keyboard.
- Switching the simulator device.
- Added the snippet on the root of the app (I thought it could be related to `@react-navigation/native`)

I don't know what else to test.

Answer (score 1):

this is iOS Simulator issues with iOS >= 14 with M1.
Try using iOS older than 14 and it should work.

Related issue that has deeper explanation: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74970#issuecomment-858170914